# Help to work on Gazebo 5.0 for a newbie in Simulation

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hallo,

Firstly sorry If I talk any wrong, I never worked in Gazebo Simulation or similar kind of projects.
I am using ros(Indigo) as middleware for my project. Now I would like to work on Gazebo 5.0 which is supported by ros jade distro, I installed ros jade parallel with indigo. I couldn't able to understand even beginner tutorials in gazebosim.org tutorials, could any one please suggest me how to work on gazebo.

Thanks for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8935/help-to-work-on-gazebo-5.0-for-a-newbie-in-simulation/) by [RavitejaG](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1244/ravitejag/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are a number of threads explaining exactly this. I would recommend only diverting from default package configurations if you are really missing something. Having 2 versions of ROS will probably complicate things if you're just starting to learn.

If you don't need Gazebo5, simply install Indigo which includes Gazebo2 with `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full`.

If you really need Gazebo5, do the same (install ROS Indigo) and then remove gazebo2 and install gazebo5 and gazebo5 wrappers. Check this thread: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8598/how-to-install-ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control-with/. There's an official page as well but this one doesn't include any step by step manual; it's here: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8598/how-to-install-ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control-with/

As for understanding the beginner tutorials, the step after installation in the tutorials is Getting Started, did you follow that and then continue on to Build a Robot? Maybe you can be more clear on what you don't understand or what you plan to achieve?

---

Originally posted by [niall](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1200/niall/) with karma: 96 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1